# A text inside a div takes the div left

Tags: html, css

I have made this div:

```
    <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; top:39px; right:70%;">
<div style="border-left:1px solid black; position:absolute; right:0px; background-color:white; top:0%; bottom:0%; height:100%; z-index:-1;">
    </div>
</div>
```

but when i add text inside the div like this:

```
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; top:39px; right:70%;">
<div style="border-left:1px solid black; position:absolute; right:0px; background-color:white; top:0%; bottom:0%; height:100%; z-index:-1;">
dddddddddddddddddddddd
    </div>
</div>
```

it takes the div left. i want the div to stay in the exact same place and the the text to float right.

here it is in jsfiidle:

[without a text inside](http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/52/)

[with a text inside](http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/53/)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please avoid using inline styles. It causes style duplication, and makes your code unreadable and hard to work with - especially for others. [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add width 100% for the div.

Instead of this

```
<div style="border-left:1px solid black; position:absolute; right:0px; background-color:white; top:0%; bottom:0%; height:100%; z-index:-1;">
```

Use this.

```
<div style="border-left:1px solid black; position:absolute; right:0px; background-color:white; top:0%; bottom:0%; height:100%; z-index:-1; width:100%;">
```

Updated jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/2fDQz/55/

Comment: in fact `width:0` **does** work. `100%`, `50%`, ... does not matter here, all make the actual width to be `0`. So the text overflows on the right side. The OP should understand it before using this solution, otherwise there may be some unexpected result in future.

Comment: One of the unexpected behaviors is the lines break at spaces, so each line can contain only 1 word (no spaces).

Answer (score 1):

Why have you nested the divs then , separating the divs makes it work

```
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; top:39px; right:70%;">

</div>
<div style="border-left:1px solid black; position:absolute; right:0px; background-color:white; top:0%; bottom:0%; height:100%; z-index:-1;">
 ddddddddddddddddddddd
 </div>
```

And if you want both divs to start from the same place from top then change 'top' attribute in the second div to the same as in the first one :-

```
<div style="border-left:1px solid black; position:absolute; right:0px; background-color:white; top:39px; bottom:0%; height:100%; z-index:-1;">
 ddddddddddddddddddddd
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your div as below:

```
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; top:39px; left:30%; width:100%;">
    <div style="border-left:1px solid black; background-color:white; width:70%;                  height:100%; text-align:right;">
dddddddddddddddddddddd
</div>
```

[Please click for the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mizanurahma/DLgmy/)